# Failed to get list of R functions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im just finished installing R in my MS Visual Code environment and besides the codes are running ok im getting the warning message "Failed to get list of R functions. Make sure that `jsonlite` is installed and r.rpath.windows points to a valid R executable."

I have done some of the workarounds and trying to fix this for a while including the R path to the settings in the extension tab but im still getting the same.

Has anyone experienced the same situation or know whats going on here please?

Comment: Are you running R through anaconda? I am and I suspect that's the culprit. That the extension is only looking for a system wide install or can't navigate the conda env pathing.

Comment: See https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/946